# Question about Joint probability density function

Tags: probability

[image]

How can I provide a mathematical expression for $f(x,y)$.

Please give me clarification.

Comment: @Dale, the *area* exceeds one, but that just means the uniform density ($C$) in that area must be less than one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The diagram indicates that probability density is uniformly distributed over a shape, which can only be represented by a piecewise function.

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} C & : (-3\leq y\leq 0) \;\wedge\; (-2\leq x\leq 2) \\[1ex] C & : (0\leq y\leq 3) \;\wedge\; (-1\leq x\leq 3) \end{cases}$$

Now determine the constant $C$ given that the (double) integral of the probability density function over its support (that area) must equal one.

$$1 = \int_{-3}^0\int_{-2}^{2} f(x,y)\operatorname d x\operatorname d y + \int_0^3\int_{-1}^3 f(x,y)\operatorname d x\operatorname d y$$

---

**Hint:** The double integral of a constant over a region is just the area of that region times the constant.

Comment: How can I slove it (how can I find constan C) when there are two intervals.

Comment: @sara integrate each interval separately and then add the results together. Also: $$\int_{h_a}^{h_b}\int_{w_a}^{w_b} c \operatorname d x\operatorname d y = (h_b-h_a)\cdot (w_b-w_a)\cdot c$$